# Postgres: Which is the order execution of triggers that are specified for different releations but activated by the same event?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm new to database triggers and I'm stuck with this:

Suppose that I have two different relations, R1 and R2, for which I specify two "independent" triggers. I mean, trigger TR1 for R1 and TR2 for R2. And suppose that both triggers are fired for the same event.

**Which will be their execution order?**

PostrgresSQL documentation states what happens for triggers defined on the *same* relation. But it's not clear about triggers defined on different relations, yet fired by the same event. I wonder if, in such situation, triggers are fired in a random order.

> [36.1. Overview of Trigger Behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/trigger-definition.html): If more than one trigger is defined *for the same event **on the same relation***, the triggers will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger name. In the case of before triggers, the possibly-modified row returned by each trigger becomes the input to the next trigger. If any before trigger returns NULL, the operation is abandoned for that row and subsequent triggers are not fired.

Comment: How will you produce an event that will fire both triggers?

Comment: BTW It may be easier to create a test setup and get an answer from it.

Comment: Actually this is not the best approach. For instance, `notify()` (to release object monitor's waiting threads) randomly chooses a thread to release. However, just by change, the randomly thread selection may match a FILO (or FIFO) release policy, making you assume wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... suppose that both triggers are fired for the same event.

This can only happen in 2 cases (in PostgreSQL):

1. With referential integrity constraint(s) (such as foreign keys)
2. Cascade/recursive trigger firing

#### Referential integrity constraints

These type of constraints will create a trigger to ensure referential integrity. In case of foreign keys, the (automatically) created trigger will have names like `RI_ConstraintTrigger...` <kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d2958/4)</kbd>. The same rule applies to them (they will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger name amongst other triggers) except in one case: they can be deferred ([globally](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html), or [initially deferred per constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)). Which means that they will be executed only at the end of the current transaction (or when `SET CONSTRAINTS` changes the mode of a constraint from `DEFERRED` to `IMMEDIATE`).

You can also create custom constraint triggers with [`CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html), which will behave the same.

#### Cascade/recursive trigger firing

This is explicitly mentioned on the docs:

> If a trigger function executes SQL commands then these commands might fire triggers again. This is known as cascading triggers. There is no direct limitation on the number of cascade levels. It is possible for cascades to cause a recursive invocation of the same trigger; for example, an INSERT trigger might execute a command that inserts an additional row into the same table, causing the INSERT trigger to be fired again. It is the trigger programmer's responsibility to avoid infinite recursion in such scenarios.

Their order are pretty straightforward, f.ex:

If `UPDATE` on `R1` will trigger `TR1` that `UPDATE`s `R2`, which will trigger `TR2` (and both `BEFORE` triggers):

```
1) BEFORE triggers of R1 (f.ex. TR1)
   1.1) BEFORE triggers of R2 (f.ex. TR2)
   1.2) INSTEAD OF triggers of R2 (or do the actual operation)
   1.3) AFTER triggers of R2
2) INSTEAD OF triggers of R1 (or do the actual operation)
3) AFTER triggers of R1
```

#### You could think, there is one more: what about [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html)?

Inheried tables not just doesn't inherit triggers, they won't fire their ancestors' triggers neither.

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d2958/4)</kbd>

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your answer: On both identified situation--where triggers associated to different tables may fire under the same event--the execution order of those triger's actions **will never be randomly**. That is, triggers **execute** always in a deterministic order (at least in Postgres). Right? Thanks!

Comment: @DiogoAnjos yes, basically. But i may note that in these cases above there is always a secondary event (*fired* by the first event), which fires its own triggers.

Comment: @pozs `rel` has 2 internal triggers. I just want to make sure I understand it. Those two are: trigger from `child` (because of `INHERITS` clause) and trigger from `aggrel` (because of `REFERENCES` clause which is actually a `FOREIGN KEY`) ? Because `aggrel` also has two internal triggers which in my understanding are covering the same referrences?

Comment: @ConsiderMe no, inherited tables does not inherit triggers, nor constraints. Foreign key owns both internal triggers, one for update and one for delete.